# How to change active configuration all projects in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have more than 50 projects in my eclipse work space. I would like to know if there is a way to change active configuration of all the projects with single setting instead of doing it for each project individually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ctrl+A" to select all projects in project explorer. Right click and select Build Configurations -> Set Active ->

This way you can change Active configuration of all projects in the workspace

Answer (score 0):

The Project General / Paths and Symbols / References you can change the configuration for every referenced project or all together at once. After you change the checkboxes you can check the folders as per your need to change the active configurations for all projects in a work space in eclipse.

Comment: The question is not about configuration of referenced projects. I want to change the active configuration of all projects in project explorer from debug to release

Comment: On the debug-config creation dialog, you click Debug to launch the debugger. Later, when you want to restart the debugger, F11 does it. To change the active configuration, you have to bring up the debug-config dialog for that config and start debugging through that button.